# Diamond question mark showing up in HTML (from MySqli)

Tags: character-encoding, collation

I have a database which I fill directly in PhpMyAdmin. There are some special characters like é in it. In PhpMyAdmin, they show perfectly. When I convert them to PDF with FPDF/PHP they show perfectly as well. When I want to show them in HTML (with PHP), they become diamond shapes with a question mark in it.

I know this has something to do with charsets and collation, but I'm a total noob on that matter. My database has collation `latin1_swedish_ci` and I want to keep it that way. My page has `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">` in the header, so they should be the same I think, still, I get question mark diamonds... How do I get the characters I want?

**Please don't say I have to convert everything to `utf-8`.** I really want to keep `latin1_swedish_ci`. I tried `charset=utf-8` in the header and converting one of the fields in my database to `utf8_general_ci`, but that field didn't show up right either, so something else must be wrong...

Comment: possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/)

Comment: The above all assume Unicode/UTF-8, but just replace that with your favourite encoding. The important part is to be consistent all the way through with your encoding declarations, and declare your used encodings everywhere needed. The above resources tell you where.

Comment: Also, seeing "question marks with diamonds" indicates that your page is being interpreted as UTF-8/Unicode. That probably means your **HTTP headers** are declaring the wrong encoding, superseding your `<meta>` declaration.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the comments of deceze, I added to the top of my PHP:

```
<?

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1');

?>
```

Never knew that the meta-tag `http-equiv` was only a fallback!

> These tags are only fallbacks though which are only used when no HTTP Content-Type header was encountered (the wording "http-equiv" hints at this). It's also conceptually weird, since these tags are inside the document itself and the browser needs to read the document first in order to figure out what kind of document it's dealing with.

Source: [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/)

This source helped a lot! Thanks deceze!

Answer (score 0):

Put this inside `<head>` tag

```
<meta charset="iso-8859-1">
```